# Mysql 5.6 and install php5-mysql , mysql-common

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-5.6

I install Mysql 5.6 with this [documentaion](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mysql-5.6-on-ubuntu-12.10-including-memcached-plugin)(in ubuntu 13.04) , now I need to install php5-mysql and mysql-common packages. can I install them with apt-get? I think they will install mysql5.5 compatible, may some error occure! how can I do?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I install php5-mysql and mysql-common, but mysql_connect in php returns false, that means it can't connect to mysql.